# Outputting a context-appropriate error message on a missing token

Tags: error-handling, antlr

I have a grammar to parse some source code:

```
document
  : header body_block* EOF
    -> body_block*
  ;

header
  : header_statement*
  ;

body_block
  : '{' block_contents '}'
  ;

block_contents
  : declaration_list
  | ... other things ....
```

It's legal for a document to have a header without a body or a body without a header.

If I try to parse a document that looks like

```
int i;
```

then ANTLR complains that it found `int` when it was expecting `EOF`.  This is true, but I'd like it to say that it was expecting `{`.  That is, if the input contains something between the header and the EOF that's not a `body_block`, then I'd like to suggest to the user that they meant to enclose that text inside a `body_block`.

I've made a couple *almost* working attempts at this that I can post if that's illuminating, but I'm hoping that I've just missed something easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretty, but something like this would do it:

```
body_block
 : ('{')=> '{' block_contents '}'
 | t=.
   {
     if(!$t.text.equals("{")) {
       String message = "expected a '{' on line " + $t.getLine() + " near '" + $t.text + "'";
     }
     else {
       String message = "encountered a '{' without a '}' on line " + $t.getLine();
     }
     throw new RuntimeException(message);
   }
 ;
```

(*not tested, may contain syntax errors!*)

So, whenever `'{' ... '}'` is not matched, it falls through to `.`<sup>1</sup> and produces a more understandable error message.

---

<sup>1</sup> note that a `.` in a parser rule matches any token, not any character!

Comment: This worked perfectly (and was a lot prettier than any of my attempts!).  I added a syntactic predicate (`('{')=>`) to keep ANTLR from complaining that the two alternatives matched the same thing.